# How to store multiselect dropdownlist with checkbox values in database with comma seperation

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using a multi-select plugin that converts the Listbox into multi-select dropdownlist with checkbox and I want to store the selected values in the database by separating them with a comma like option1,option2.

```
   <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="bkgenres">Genres</label>
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function pageLoad() {
               document.multiselect('#bkgenres');
               document.multiselect('#bkgenres').deselectAll();
           };
        </script>
        <asp:ListBox ID="bkgenres" runat="server" CssClass="form-control multiselect-wrapper" multiple="multiple" onChange="mydun()"></asp:ListBox>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="bktype" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
     </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am using the Listbox inside an update panel and its working all fine but when i select multiple items and try to store in the database only the first selected option gets selected. This is my cs code:

```
     String get_value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < bkgenres.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (bkgenres.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                get_value = get_value + bkgenres.Items[i].Text + ",";
            }
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Books (bookname,bookauthor,bookpublisher,bookdesc,bookdate,bookedition,bookpages,booktype,bookgenre,booklanguage) values (@bkname,@bkauthor,@bkpublication,@bkdesc,@bkdate,@bkedition,@bkpages,@bktype,@bkgenres,@bklang)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkname", bkname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkauthor", bkauthor.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkpublication", bkpublication.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkdesc", bkdesc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkdate", bkrdate.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkedition", bkedition.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkpages", bkpages.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bkgenres", get_value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bktype", bktype.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bklang", bklanguages.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After adding the data I am getting output in a database table is like this option1,
The first option is entered in a database and separated by a comma but rest of the options are not saved in the table.

Comment: Have you verified that `Selected` on all of the expected items have the value `true`?

Comment: Yeah i did but its not getting stored, i tried many different methods but they all are just storing the first selected option not the rest of them

Comment: What is your field type in your database? Your input parameter value may be getting truncated.

Comment: I have a table in which there is a column bookgenres with a varchar data type.

Comment: And what is the length of said varchar field? You should see something like `varchar(100)` or `varcahr(max)` for SQL Server.